# Android Studio Documentation Dialog takes too long

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

I recently re-installed Android Studio-3.3. Dialog takes too long(3-4 sec, it was instant with my previous installation.) for fetching documentation. Also it fetches every time when I mouse hover. Is there any way to cache it. With Android Studio's previous version it was showing instantly.

[image: Android-Studio-3.3]

Comment: have you downloaded the sources for 28 with the sdk manager?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded it.

Comment: It was enough for me to download sources for corresponding API. Check your `targetSdk` in build.gradle file and download sources for this API (you need to check "Show Package Details" in SDK Manager to see it).